# Does Gedit accept JavaScript?

Tags: gedit, javascript

I have a question about Gedit. I am trying to learn JavaScript. 
I went to http://www.w3schools.com/js/ and tried the Date and Time example.

Date and Time example code:
<sup>Source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_myfirst</sup>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

After a while I copied and pasted the script into Gedit and found that it didn't work the way that it did on the W3Schools website. I am able to see something in the browser, but it does nothing when I click the button. Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image: JavaScript]

The pop-up blocker is off, and I don't know what else to do. Are there some plugins that I could use to change this? I don't need anything fancy, I really like Gedit for the most part, I would just like to be able to use it for all my coding needs. All I have learned so far is HTML and CSS.

Comment: You mean it doesn't color/highlight in the same way?

Comment: No the button is there but it has no function. On the website it will provide a date and time when clicked. But it does nothing when I copy it into gedit.

Comment: Tip: if you're going to learn javascript, you might enjoy the website [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It's an online editor for JS, HTML and CSS which allows you to experiment with these languages from a single interface. Your code example would look like this in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vnaaprmd/

Comment: As a public service, I would like to point out that W3Schools has a reputation for not always being of the highest quality. It's a lot better than it used to be, but the reference material at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ may be more reliable and up to date.

Comment: From your question and comments, this appears to be a web development question (and a massive amount of confusion as to how web pages work), which is not very well suited here.  `gedit` has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @MatthewRead-You are correct, I was confused. I was trying to see if the reason why my output was not coming out was from the text editor. I was wrong. W3Schools left out a few details and it worked for them. But when all I did was copy and paste it didn't for me. Ok, I will try to direct these types of questions elsewhere in the future.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, i just verified it myself and the code works just fine. I feel sorry for all the condescending responses you got.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the comments:

> No the button is there but it has no function. On the website it will provide a date and time when clicked. But it does nothing when I copy it into gedit.

Gedit is a *text editor*. It can edit text (and source code, etc.). To *run* the code, save it with a `.html` (for example, as `datetime.html`) because this is HTML code.

Then double-click the resulting HTML file to open (and thus run) it in your browser of choice (Firefox, Chromium, Chrome etc.).

As to why:

> On the website it will provide a date and time when clicked.

Assuming you mean this,
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLg33.png]

it is because the thing in the screenshot is not an editor. It is the *result*.

If you want an editor that also provides the *result* as a preview, try [Atom](https://atom.io) (there may be others). Write HTML in it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Perhaps I am asking the wrong question. Your comment is correct, you have to save it to a .html file and double click it, but this has been done already with no success.

Comment: @BJsgoodlife Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: @BJsgoodlife Also see the note in [the_velour_fog's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/803123/423626)

Comment: @BJsgoodlife Look at the JS console output.

Answer (score 5):

you need to

- copy the script into gedit then
- save the code as a file , then
- load the file in the browser,

`Ctrl + o` is the shortcut to open a file directly from a browser.
Note: for security reasons browsers sometimes won't allow direct execution of javascript from local files. Because the browser expects it should have been served by a webserver.

Comment: I think that last "Note:" is probably the actual answer. I've been stung by this myself, trying to play around with JS Canvas stuff, and had a total facepalm moment when I realised.